# Location can not be accessed in AsynTask while using with BroadCast Receiver , Alarm and pending Intents

Tags: android, android-asynctask, location, broadcastreceiver, android-camera-intent

I'm using Broadcast Receiver and Alarm with Pending Intent for to get my service run on BOOT_COMPLETE with some fixed timer.And im providing static values to the variable and then transmits them on to the webserver( servlet) ,till this my code works fine...
but when im adding the Location manager  to get the real coordinates the  App crashes !!
error :: NULLPOinterException, !!!
tell me where im wrong !! will be most kidnessss.. thanks !!
[also wanna to open camera when the respone being received from the servlet ,which i mentioned in comment inside the code !! ]

**This is my BroadCast REceiver**

```
    public class StartAtBootServiceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver 
{

    // receives BOOT_COMPLETed from manifest ,,plus added here Alarm
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) 
    {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        Intent srvIntent = new Intent(context, StartAtBootService.class);

        PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, srvIntent,0);
        // Use context argument to access service
        AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Repeat every 5 seconds
        alarm.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                cal.getTimeInMillis(), 10000, pIntent);
    }

}
```

**This is my Service java class**

```
    public class StartAtBootService extends Service {
    public static final String url = "http://10.0.2.2:1010/junction/AsynLocInsertionServ"; 
    String imei = "0";
    double latitude = 000;
    double longitude = 000;

    String returnString = null;
    Integer returnedValue = 0;

    private LocationManager lm;

    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        Log.d("StartServiceAtBoot1", "StartAtBootService Created1");

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d("StartServiceAtBoot2", "StartAtBootService -- onStartCommand()");

        // Get LocationManager object from System Services LOCATION_SERVICES
        lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // create a criteria object to retrieve provider
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

        // Get the name of the best provider
        String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

        // Get current Location
        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        // get latitude of the current location
        latitude = myLocation.getLatitude();

        // get longitude of the current location
        longitude = myLocation.getLongitude();

        Toast.makeText(this, "onStart tryyyy", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        deviceInfo(); // my method for getting imei

        new GetXMLTask().execute(url); // calls the AsynTask

        return START_STICKY;

    }

    public void deviceInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        TelephonyManager t = (TelephonyManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        imei = t.getDeviceId();

    }

    // *************************************************************************************************//

    private class GetXMLTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
            String output = null;

            try {
                DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

                HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

                try {

                    String latitude1 = String.valueOf(latitude);
                    String longitude2 = String.valueOf(longitude);

                    List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param1imei",
                            imei));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param2lati",
                            latitude1));
                    nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param3longi",
                            longitude2));
                    // nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("param4bts",
                    // bts));
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);

                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    output = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

                }// end of inner try block

                catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();

                }

            } // end of outer try block

            catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());

            }

            return output;

        } // end of getOutputFromUrl method

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String output) {
            super.onPostExecute(output);

            Log.d("done LAtlong stored in mysql_onPost method",
                    " " + output.toString());

            if (true) // i put this true ,because i wanna to open camera
                        // i,e if the value returned from doInBackgroud method [i,e the output variable]
                        // the condition ,then open camera
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
                getApplicationContext().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
            }

        }

    } // end of GetXMLTask

}
```

**HATE THESE ::**

```
    05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service r.fn.sender.StartAtBootService@40ce9358 with Intent { flg=0x4 cmp=r.fn.sender/.StartAtBootService (has extras) }: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2673)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1900(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1331)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at r.fn.sender.StartAtBootService.onStartCommand(StartAtBootService.java:106)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2656)
05-06 17:56:46.492: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  ... 10 more



**manifest permissions**


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" >
    </uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

Comment: Can you include the stack trace?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your LocationManager in the onCreate() method.

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Log.d("StartServiceAtBoot1", "StartAtBootService Created1");
    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
}
```

Comment: i had included all the permissions..i have put the static location as global . viz double latitude = 000; and double longitude = 000; And these get over write
 nothing is working..

Comment: remove toast message from both the hook method ,,onCreat and onstartcmd..but still not able to open camera !!!